# Why can I overload a function with disjoint template parameter options, but not a class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

This compiles:

```
template <typename T, typename T2> void foo() { std::cout << "in foo() for two types." << std::endl; }
template <typename T, T Value>     void foo() { std::cout << "in foo() for a type and a value." << std::endl; }
```

This doesn't (GCC 4.9.3 with `-std=c++11`):

```
template <typename T, typename T2> class A { A() { std::cout << "in A::A() for two types." << std::endl; } };
template <typename T, T Value>     class A { A() { std::cout << "in A::a() for a type and a value." << std::endl; } };
```

With the error being:

```
a.cpp:6:23: error: template parameter ‘class T2’
 template <typename T, typename T2> class A { A() { std::cout << "in A::A() for two types." << std::endl; } };
                       ^
a.cpp:7:42: error: redeclared here as ‘T Value’
 template <typename T, T Value>     class A { A() { std::cout << "in A::a() for a type and a value." << std::endl; } };
                                          ^
```

The second overload-of-sorts seems perfectly reasonable to me, there can be no ambiguity, since types and values are disjoint. So why is it not allowed?

Comment: There is no concept of "overloaded classes" in C++. You can only specialize a class.

Comment: @vsoftco: Aren't you kind of splitting hairs? So, don't call it overloading, but something else. The thing is, the two templated class definitions do cannot actually conflict. And if I can have different different instantiations of the same templated class for different types, why should this not be possible?

Comment: Probably because the rules would have become more complicated (they already are). Then something like `X<class T1, class T2>` and `X<class T1>` should also be valid (why not?), which, via specializations, will create a lot of nightmares. But frankly I believe it was just a matter of practicality and keeping the standard as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just how class templates work. You start with a primary template:

```
template <class T, class U> struct A;
```

And then you can specialize it. All of the specializations must match the primary:

```
template <class T> struct A<T, T> {...}; // OK
template <class T> struct A<T> {...}; // nope
```

That's simply how it's currently defined: first lookup the primary, then pick the specialization based on partial ordering rules.

To allow for what you want would be a pretty large change in the language for picking the correct class template. Especially in light of the fact that you can simply achieve what you want with:

```
template <class T, T V>
struct A<T, std::integral_constant<T, V>> {...};
```

Comment: integral constant doesn't work with floats. But, well, that's what I've been sort of doing.